# How rename 2 files without any loop in Java

Tags: java, rest

I have a REST Controller class which receives 2 files from Angular Controller. I have understood that for security reasons it is advised to change the file names at server side rather than client side.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST, headers=("content-type=multipart/*"))
public @ResponseBody void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("id") int id ) {

        try {
              FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getBytes(), new FileOutputStream("D:/Workspace/OLPV/WebContent/documents/"+file.getOriginalFilename()));

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String docPath ="documents/"+file.getOriginalFilename();

        Document doc = new Document(id, docPath);

        documentService.addItem(doc);

     }
```

I want to rename the files before storing them to avoid duplication of files. for example if 2 files get uploaded with the name test.pdf. I dont have any loop in REST Controller so that I can do test_[index].pdf. Anyone could help me on this?

Comment: you can use current time in milliseconds after the filename

Comment: Could you please explain with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what you can use instead of index:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
FileCopyUtils.copy(file.getBytes(), new FileOutputStream("D:/Workspace/OLPV/WebContent/documents/"+currentTime+file.getOriginalFilename()));
```

and also change

```
String docPath ="documents/"+currentTime+file.getOriginalFilename();
```

Comment: I'm getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Workspace\OLPV\WebContent\documents\Thu Nov 19 14:46:33 IST 2015Fees.pdf (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: Sorry, The system can't create a file with characters ':'. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is a way to have unique names server-side then you can use UUID to name your files.

```
final File parent = new File("documents");
final File docFile = new File(parent, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html